Aws python lambda failing to connect to on-prem oracle DB
I am writing a lambda using python which is connecting to my on-prem oracle db.
My lambda is deployed in private VPC and subnets from where I have connection to my DB. I am also running a fargate under same vpc and subnets which is successfully able to connect to the db but lambda is failing with error resource busy.
Here is my lambda :
import json
import oracledb

def create_oracle_connection():
    print('Creating DB Connection')
    connection = oracledb.connect(
        user='testenv1',
        password='testenv1',
        dsn='nagTasj12-scan.ato.com:1521/?service_name=ATOODHAS2.ato.com',
    )
    print('Created DB Connection')
    return connection

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    event_uuid = "2"
    # Print the event ID
    print(f'Received event ID: {event_uuid}')
    event = {} 
    # Connect to Oracle database
    connection = create_oracle_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()

And Here is the error i a getting
    {
  "errorMessage": "DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=sfdfsdf+fsdffsd==).\n[Errno 16] Device or resource busy",
  "errorType": "OperationalError",
  "requestId": "9ac84a89-2131-4275-b1c2-gdsgsg232sdf",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/event_processor.py\", line 20, in lambda_handler\n    connection = create_oracle_connection()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/event_processor.py\", line 6, in create_oracle_connection\n    connection = oracledb.connect(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oracledb/connection.py\", line 1158, in connect\n    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oracledb/connection.py\", line 541, in __init__\n    impl.connect(params_impl)\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 381, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 377, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 337, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 318, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description\n",
    "  File \"src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx\", line 288, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oracledb/errors.py\", line 181, in _raise_err\n    raise error.exc_type(error) from cause\n"
  ]
}

What can be the possible reason.
I have fully opened the lambda’s security group’s outbound rules.

Is the lambda in a public subnet or private?

Please Edit your Question and provide the exact error message. Also, please tell us more about the path from the Lambda function to the on-prem database. For example, what resources/endpoints/VPNs is it going through? Is the Lambda function connected to multiple subnets, or just one?

This lambda is in private network and in same subnet my fargate is able to access the database.

Lambda function is connected to 2 subnets, same as fargate.
